# Pandas how to compare two csv file for delete duplicate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have two csv file csv1 and csv2.  Now I will to delete all record from csv2 if any record match with csv1. Both csv have unique identifier sku.

csv1:

```
sku    name 
Gk125  Jhone
GK126  Mike
```

csv2:

```
sku    name 
   Gk127  Doe
   GK128  Hock
   GK126  Mike #this is the duplicate record which already in csv1
```

my expected result for csv2 will be

```
  sku    name 
   Gk127  Doe
   GK128  Hock
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
old_file = list(old['sku'])
updated = new[~new['sku'].isin(old)]
updated.to_csv('...my path/updated.csv')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'sku':['Gk125', 'GK126'], 'name':['Jhone', 'Mike']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'sku':['Gk127', 'GK128', 'GK126'], 'name':['Doe', 'Hock', 'Mike']})

print(df2[~df2['sku'].isin(df1['sku'])])
```

Output:

```
     sku  name
0  Gk127   Doe
1  GK128  Hock
```